# Free allocated memory by a nested tree

Tags: c++

I have a nested binary search tree, in this tree each node contains a pointer to an other BST. I wrote this code to delete my tree and free the allocated memory:

```
void reclaimMemory(LayerTwo::Node* n){//delete the second tree
    if (n == nullptr) return;
    reclaimMemory(n->left);
    reclaimMemory(n->right);

    delete n;
}

void reclaimMemory(LayerOne::Node* n){//delete the first tree
    if (n == nullptr) return;
    reclaimMemory(n->left);
    reclaimMemory(n->right);

    reclaimMemory(n->layerTwotree->root);

    delete n;
}
```

This code gives me no errors and everything seems OK. But I was wondering if I'm using the right method to free the allocated memory by the tree, Are there any better ways of doing this task?

Comment: I believe this should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com if you have no errors

Comment: The obvious other way is to delete the left and right subtrees in the destructor of `Node`. Another way would be to use smart pointers, so the cleanup is automatic.

Comment: @john The problem with smart pointers is that Im using boost library and I have implemented a red-black tree based on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/node_algorithms.html I dont know how can I use unique_ptr in boost custom node trails, so I had to free the allocated memory by myself.